# Disable a page in VB.net for a particular time

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to disable a page which is opened while clicking a hyperlink in my application. My application is developed using VB.Net.
Can we use Timer function?

Comment: And what do you mean by disable?  When the hyperlink is clicked do you want a 404 returned?  When the hyperlink is clicked, do you want the rendered page to be read-only?

Comment: i need to display some message like "Maintenance in progress try later" in that page rather than displaying the page usual functionality

Comment: i need to display the message everyday at a particualr time

Comment: If that page has any functionality, I would also make sure each of these are disabled.

Comment: Error message:
Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
 Code used:
 Dim start_time As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6) Dim end_time As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8) If Date.Now.TimeOfDay >= start_time And Date.Now.TimeOfDay <= end_time Then MsgBox("Maintenance under progress please try placing order after 01:00 AM", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground) Response.Redirect("Main.aspx") End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to display a maintenance notification message.  My preferred method is to use a database table called MaintenanceNotification.

Then, when you load the page, check the database for an existing notification, if there is one, handle appropriately.

```
**MaintenanceNotification**
MaintenanceNotificationId
StartDate
EndDate
Message
Comments
```

**EDIT**

To show a message at the same time every day, when the page loads, compare [DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) to the time you want the messaged displayed (use a TimeSpan).

Psuedo Code:

```
If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay is >= start time AND ALSO DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= end time THEN
     'display the message.
END IF
```

Comment: i need to display the message everyday at a particualr time

Comment: @venkatesh, I updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: @venkatesh, no problem.  If this solution helped, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.

Comment: im not getting any error while debugging the coed but after publishing the code im getting the below error

Comment: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Code used:

Dim start_time As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6)
Dim end_time As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8)
If Date.Now.TimeOfDay >= start_time And Date.Now.TimeOfDay <= end_time Then
MsgBox("Maintenance under progress please try placing order after 01:00 AM", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
Response.Redirect("Main.aspx")  
End If

Comment: @venkatesh, this needs to be a new question.